# Zope 2 error: The current user does not have the required "View" permission

Tags: zope, plone-4.x

I can't add contents in some folders of my website. The following error appears in error_log

```
The current user does not have the required "View" permission
```

But I am using the admin user.

Plone 4.1.5, Zope 2.13.13

Answer (score 0):

You can try to debug this by using the `manage_reportUserPermissions` view:

http://your-instance/path/to/folder/manage_reportUserPermissions?user=admin

You need to be logged in with sufficient rights, of course.